# Console.log outputs false result [Weird Behaviour]

Tags: javascript

I have a string where I use `split('')` to convert into an array. I just want to delete the last item of an array using `splice()`.

However, I get this weird result when I output the array after deleting the last item. It outputs fine when I don't use `console.log() in` Chrome console. Why is this happening?

(Try this code in the console. It outputs fine)

```
let strings = 'AA11111';
let splits = strings.split("");
splits.splice(0, splits.length - 1);
```

(This gives me the false result. [Outputs the last item of the array.])

```js
let strings = 'AA11111';
let splits = strings.split("");
splits.splice(0, splits.length - 1);
console.log(splits);
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.splice` modifies the array it is called on.

Comment: `splits.splice(-1)` or just `splits.pop()` to remove the last item of an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) used to remove elements from an array and change the content of the original array and it take in the first parameter the index at which you need to delete elements and next parameter the number of elements to delete , so if you need to delete the last element you need to start at **arr.length-1** and delete count should be **1** look at the example below

```js
let strings = 'AA11111';
let splits = strings.split("");
splits.splice(splits.length - 1,1);
console.log(splits);
```

Comment: Good explanation!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback

Comment: But why does it work without using console.log() (in my code)?

Comment: Because the splice function returns the deleted elements as a new array. Whenever you call a function in the console, the `return` value of that function is shown. It's all in the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: @connexo Gotcha!

Answer (score 1):

Here what happens is that **all elements except the last one are removed**. And that is the reason why you get modified array with just 1 element when you console.log. And **in the first case it is returning the deleted items**.

```
splits.splice(0, splits.length - 1);
```

The first paramenter is the start position of the element to be deleted and second parameter is the number of elements

Comment: I get it! Thanks.

Comment: It also works fine when I give a variable to that code and output that variable.

Answer (score 0):

This output makes sense to me.

Reading from the [Array.prototype#splice documentation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

> **Syntax**
>
> `array.splice(start[, deleteCount[, item1[, item2[, ...]]]])`
>
> Parameters
>
> **start**
>
> Index at which to start changing the array (with origin 0). If greater
>   than the length of the array, actual starting index will be set to the
>   length of the array. If negative, will begin that many elements from
>   the end of the array (with origin -1) and will be set to 0 if absolute
>   value is greater than the length of the array.
>
> **deleteCount** Optional
>
> An integer indicating the number of old array elements to remove.

You start at index 0, ('A'), you delete length-1 elements (six elements). You're left with the last element. ('1').

If you want to delete the last element I would do this:

```js
let strings = 'AA11111';
let splits = strings.split("");
splits.splice(-1, 1); //starting at the last element, delete one element. 
console.log(splits);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here what happens is that all elements except the last one are removed. And that is the reason why you get modified array with just 1 element when you console.log. And in the first case it is returning the deleted items.

```js
splits.splice(0, splits.length - 1);
```

```html
 The modified array with just 1 element when you console.log. And in the first case it is returning the deleted items.
```